# Laptop for IT Sys Admin

Tags: laptop, windows

I am a System Admin at an IT Support Services company that supports small and medium sized businesses in the DC metro area.  My boss is getting ready to purchase me a laptop for work.  Not having a laptop with me all day is limiting my efficiency in handling calls I get while on-site with a client; with a laptop I can provide remote support or answers for certain tasks instead of waiting until I get back to my computer at the office.

Essential Specs:

- Size: 15.6 or smaller with 1920x1080 resolution or better
- CPU: Quad Core Intel i5 or i7
- Memory: DDR4 8gb or more expandable (would be open to non-expandable ram depending on what other laptop suggestions)
- Keyboard: As close to full sized as possible; keys cannot be too shallow and/or too small.  Number pad would be nice but is not required.
- WiFi: Dual Band AC

I would like the laptop to have both a HDD for storage and a PCIe NVME SSD for Windows and apps.  Not getting the NVME SSD is not a deal breaker by any means just something that would be useful to me.  I would use the SSD for my boot/app drive and the a HDD SATA drive for storage.

Comment: Is the price an issue here? Are there any brand preferences? Are there any battery life requirements? Do you want ECC RAM if possible?

Comment: If possible I would like to stick to around $1000, not a whole lot more.  As far as brand, anything buy Acer is worth considering.  It would be nice to get 4-5 hours, or be able to buy extra or larger battery.  ECC ram is not a requirement.

Comment: I can't issue a formal recommendation or something, but the [Acer Aspire V7 Nitros](http://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/series/aspirevnitro) look like what you're looking for.